# Is it possible to share my speakers between a PS3 and PC?

Tags: audio, speakers

I own a pair of [these speakers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003VAHYTG). Currently, the PC is plugged in via the PC port (3.5m jack) and this is fine. I have a PS3 connected to my TV as well - the PS3 is beside the TV. Given the ports on these speakers, can I share the speakers somehow?

Comment: Would this product be feasible? http://www.amazon.com/Generic-23-3-5mm-Jack-Splitter/dp/B001E3ZM8M

Comment: Does your tv have another audio out RCA jack?  If so, you get another RCA cable and run it to the RCA input of your speakers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. According to the information available at the link you provided;

> RCA and 3.5mm inputs make it easy to plug in up to three audio
>   devices?your computer, iPod, game console, DVD player and more

If needed, you can adapt 3.5mm to RCA to connect another device with 3.5mm output. The cables are inexpensive.

[image]

Comment: Won't these plugs only give 2.0? Or will they do 2.1?